# How can I download play counts from LastFM to Banshee 2.6.1 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, banshee

How would I download play counts from Last FM to my Banshee 2.6.1 on Ubuntu 13.04 installation?

I know that the there is a banshe-lastfm-sync-master script on github, but I can't get it to work.

Can any one advise how the play counts can be obtained?

Comment: Can you tell us how did you solved, please? See [Can I answer my own question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was solved by the following steps:

Googled "install module cpan".

Followed instructions to install "cpan App::cpanminus".

Then installed modules using "cpanm Module::Name" by running the banhsee script, and catching the errors for each missing module.

Then used the script like this:

```
./banshee-lastfm-sync --key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026 --username=xxxxx --db=/home/xxxxx/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db"
```

The key came from the script. I don't know why it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://github.com/psychonaut/banshe-lastfm-sync/blob/master/banshee-lastfm-sync) contains the script that you talked about. I don't know if it works anymore, it's a little outdated (from 2012/07/08), but you can try running it. Do you have Perl installed on your system?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I get this error:./banshee-lastfm-sync 
Can't locate Data/Dump.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./banshee-lastfm-sync line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./banshee-lastfm-sync line 8.

Comment: Try installing the [**Data/Dump** module from CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/Data/Data-Dump-1.22.tar.gz).

Comment: Thanks.  Googled "install module cpan".  Followed instructions to install "cpan App::cpanminus". Then installed modules using "cpanm Module::Name" by running the banhsee script, and catching the errors for each missing module.

Comment: Now I just need to know how to use this script.  The README is empty and the built in script help is insufficient.  :-(

Comment: Ok.  A bit of playing gives me what it need.  The command line "./banshee-lastfm-sync --key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026 --username=xxxxx --db=/home/xxxxx/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db" worked!  The key came from the script.  I don't know why it was needed.

Comment: Problem solved?